# Ionic alert controller: placeholder not working on input type file

Tags: ionic3, placeholder, input-type-file

I have an Ionic alert controller that contains an input of type file. I set the placeholder text in the input configuration, like this:

[image]

But when the alert is prompted a default text is shown as shown below:

[image]

Am I missing something to configure? By the way, how can I change the default text for the select file button?

Comment: please share full code snippet of how exactly you are using Alert Controller with input...

Comment: snippet updated, hope it helps

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ionic Alert Controller documentation, Placeholder property only works for textual and numeric inputs.